# XCM Reserve transfer between trappist and asset hub

Tags: xcm, trappist

I am locally running the `zombienet/trappist_rococo.toml` network.

I create assets on both chains using the `assets.create` extrinsic. On asset hub I mint tokens to Alice.

After that, I call the `limitedReserveTransfer` extrinsic like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

However I get the following error when making the call:

```
error: FailedToTransactAsset
```

I don't really understand why is this failing so I would appreciate it if someone could explain the reason, or show an example of a successful reserve transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if your registered asset is sufficient. In polkadot.js, Developer > ChainState > assets > asset(). If `isSufficient` is false, you can update it through Extrinsics > assets > forceAssetStatus. Otherwise, you need to ensure that the account receiving the asset has enough(ED) native assets

> There are two types of assets on Asset Hub: sufficient and non-sufficient.
> To hold a non-sufficient asset in an account, the account needs to exist on-chain, which means it needs to have a balance in the native asset at least as much as the Existential Deposit (ED). This means 0.1 DOT on Polkadot Asset Hub and 0.000003333 KSM on Kusama Asset Hub. These existential deposits are ten times smaller than those on the Relay Chains.
> So, to send a non-sufficient asset, you need to ensure that the recipient account has at least the ED. A sufficient asset doesn't require the account to have any balance in the native token to be received.

Comment: Thanks, this did resolve the error I was receiving on the sender side. However, the assets hub parachain does not have the sudo pallet so I had to add that manually. There is probably a way to forceAssetStatus from the relay chain just couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Rococo has the sudo pallet, you can call forceAssetStatus by sending an XCM from Rococo to AssetHub use sudo. And please note you should use the originType:Superuser to transact the force call. Well this is off topic. If you still have problems, you can ask a new question, I will be happy to help you