# XCM TooExpensive when reserve transferring

Tags: xcm, hrmp, trappist

I am running a local network containing an AssetHub and the Trappist parachain.

I create assets on both chains, and I make the one on AssetHub a sufficient asset.

I register the asset on the Trappist chain using `assetRegistry.registerReserveAsset`:

[image]

When I initiate a reserve transfer from AssetHub to Trappist the execution on AssetHub succeeds, but I get the `TooExpensive` error on the receiver side.

NOTE: the reserve transfer instruction looks like the one [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9525/xcm-reserve-transfer-between-trappist-and-asset-hub), the only two differences being the `assetId` is zero and I transfer a much greater amount (10000000000000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trappist does not support using the Asset you are using to pay for execution fees. Currently it supports USDT, Realy token, native token. You can change the trader to support more tokens.
https://github.com/paritytech/trappist/blob/v0.9.42/runtime/trappist/src/xcm_config.rs#L258

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have the similar problem but different solution that I don't understand now:). So, my setup is: Westend relay, Westmint and custom parachains. Both paras have assets with id 1984. Westmint asset has been made sufficient and registered on custom parachain as on screenshot but in my case `assetId` - 1984 and `GeneralIndex` - 1984. When I initiate `polkadotXcm.limitedReserveTransfer` on Westmint I got an error `TooExpensive` on custom para. And I changed trader as you mentioned to support more tokens: `X3(Parachain(1000), PalletInstance(50), GeneralIndex(1984)`