# XcmError::TooExpensive When trasfering fungible assets between statemine & trappist parachains with rococo relay chain (limitedReservedTransferAssets)

Tags: parachain, xcm, xcmp, cross-chain

I'm trying to test transfer of fungible assets from Statemine to Trappist with Rococo relay chain to integrate assets to my custom parachain. First of all, I tried to repeat the steps shown in the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfxU3hUprKo&t=1182s) with standard configs:

Steps:

1. Clone `polkadot` repo & swith to branch `release-v0.9.42`. Build with `cargo build --release` and copy `target/release/polkadot` to use it with zombienet.
2. Clone `cumulus` repo & switch to branch `polkadot-v0.9.42`. Change `Barrier` config to allow messages from `rococo` to make fungible asset sufficient from this:

`pub type Barrier = DenyThenTry<DenyReserveTransferToRelayChain, (TakeWeightCredit, AllowKnownQueryResponses<PolkadotXcm>, WithComputedOrigin<(AllowTopLevelPaidExecutionFrom<Everything>, AllowExplicitUnpaidExecutionFrom<Everything>, AllowSubscriptionsFrom<Everything>,), UniversalLocation, ConstU32<8>,>,),>;`

to this:

`pub type Barrier = DenyThenTry<DenyReserveTransferToRelayChain, (TakeWeightCredit, AllowTopLevelPaidExecutionFrom<Everything>, AllowUnpaidExecutionFrom<Everything>, AllowKnownQueryResponses<PolkadotXcm>, AllowSubscriptionsFrom<Everything>,),>;`.

Build with cargo build --release and copy target/release/polkadot to use it with zombienet.

3. Clone `trappist` repo & switch to branch `polkadot-v0.9.42`. Build with cargo build --release and copy target/release/polkadot to use it with zombienet.
4. Start all nodes (rococo with 4 validators, statemine & trappist with 1 collator both).
5. On trappist parachain call `lockdownMode.deactivateLockdownMode` to allow interactions.
6. Create a fungible asset on statemine & trappist.
7. Make fungible asset from statemine sufficient using this `encoded call data` instruction

[image]

by calling it on relay chain with `sudo`.

[image]

Got event `assets.AssetStatusChanged` on statemine.

8. Mint `10_000_000` fungible tokens on statemine and transfer to `BOB` account `10_000`.
9. After that create extrinsic call `polkadotXcm.limitedReserveTransferAssets` as below:

[image]
[image]

10. Received event on statemine LGTM:

[image]

11. But I have problem with event on trappist. Got error:

[image]

So, my question is what I should do to get rid of this error and succesfully transfer fungible assets between parachains?

I can add more information about configs or something else.

Thanks in advance to everyone who will take part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made Trappist support your asset? If not, Trappist doesn't support using your asset to pay for execution fees. You can change the [Trader](https://github.com/paritytech/trappist/blob/v0.9.42/runtime/trappist/src/xcm_config.rs#L258) in Trappist to support it. Check this answer: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/9603/1959

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helps me with this issue and `xcmError::TooExpensive` is gone. But, after that i got an error `FailedToTransactAsset` on the receiving chain (trappist). It can be related to unsufficient balance on parachain sovereign account, but I checked all balances and transfer needed amount of tokens on relay chain to: `parachain1000` and `parachain1001` sovereign account, on `parachain1000` to `parachain1001` sovereign account and on `parachain1001` to `parachain1000` sovereign account. Maybe you know something about this error? 
@Guantong

Comment: It was off topic, cloud you open a new question and add more information?